# AngularJS Bootstrap Gallery landscape and portrait images

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've built a site with AngularJS, bootstrap and Wordpress.

The gallery should be able to display two portrait images side by side in a row and landscape images on a single row. I've stumbled across this post http://codepen.io/horne3754sg/pen/vNBdgB where someone to find pairs in an array of images and builds up a grid, but he's not using Bootstrap.

I want the gallery to go into stack mode at a certain breakpoint, which is not the case in this example. Another problem I'm facing is that in the example above, he's using a predefined array with images and I use a asynchronous request to retrieve my images, so I'm not able to find pairs in my array of images. So far this is my code:

AngularJS:

```
    return $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/projects/?status=publish&slug=' + url).success(function(res) {
        WPService.project = res;

        // We retrieve all sizes for each image in the project
        let project_attached_images_length = WPService.project[0].attached_images.length;

        for(let i=0; i< project_attached_images_length; i++) {
            $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/media/' + WPService.project[0].attached_images[i].ID).success(function(res) {
                WPService.project_images[i] = res;

                let image = new Image();
                image.src = WPService.project_images[i].source_url;
                WPService.project_images[i].width  = image.width;
                WPService.project_images[i].height = image.height;

                if(WPService.project_images[i].width <= WPService.project_images[i].height)
                    WPService.project_images[i].orientation = 'portrait';
                else
                    WPService.project_images[i].orientation = 'landscape';

                //console.log(i + ' ' + WPService.project_images[i].source_url + ' ' + WPService.project_images[i].dimension);
                //console.log(WPService.project_images[i]);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

HTML code:

```
            <div ng-repeat="project in data.project">
              <div class="row" ng-repeat="image in project.attached_images track by $index" ng-hide="$index == 0">
                <div ng-class="{ 'col-md-1': !isToggled, 'col-md-0': isToggled }"></div>
                <div ng-class="{ 'col-md-10': !isToggled, 'col-md-12': isToggled }">
                  <div class="project-image afkl-lazy-wrapper afkl-img-ratio-1-1" afkl-lazy-image="{{ data.project_images[$index].media_details.sizes.medium.source_url }} 640w, {{ data.project_images[$index].media_details.sizes.large.source_url }} 768w, {{ image.guid }}"></div>
                  <p class="project-photos-excerpt">{{ image.post_excerpt }} - {{ data.project_images[$index].orientation }}</p>
                </div><!-- .col-md-10 -->
                <div ng-class="{ 'col-md-1': !isToggled, 'col-md-0': isToggled }"></div>
              </div><!-- .row -->
            </div><!-- ng-repeat wrapper -->
```

Maybe there's another solution someone has found, Masonary for example? (I just came across this)

How do I get the portrait images side by side in my grid? The array does not have a fixed order, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution. Instead of printing a separate Bootstrap row/column for each image, I made one container with a UL table, putting the IMG inside of LI's inline-block. This way you can ng-repeat without having the worry about rows:

CSS:

```
#project-photos {
    list-style: none;
    display:table;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
#project-photos li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#project-photos li.portrait {
    width:50%;
    padding:0 1% 1% 1%;
}
#project-photos li.landscape {
    width:100%;
    padding:0 1% 1% 1%;
}
.project-image img {
    display:block;
  max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:auto
}
```

HTML

```
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="project in data.project">
              <div ng-class="{ 'col-md-1': !isToggled, 'col-md-0': isToggled }"></div>
              <div ng-class="{ 'col-md-10': !isToggled, 'col-md-12': isToggled }">
                <ul id="project-photos">
                  <li ng-repeat="image in project.attached_images track by $index" class="{{ data.project_images[$index].class }}" ng-if="$index != 0">
                    <div class="project-image" afkl-lazy-image="{{ data.project_images[$index].media_details.sizes.medium.source_url }} 640w, {{ data.project_images[$index].media_details.sizes.large.source_url }} 768w, {{ image.guid }}"></div>
                    <p class="project-photos-excerpt" ng-if="image.post_excerpt">{{ image.post_excerpt }}</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- .col-md-10 -->
              <div ng-class="{ 'col-md-1': !isToggled, 'col-md-0': isToggled }"></div>
            </div><!-- .row -->
```

Angular:

```
    return $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/projects/?slug=' + url).success(function(res) {
        WPService.project = res;

        // We retrieve all sizes for each image in the project
        let project_attached_images_length = WPService.project[0].attached_images.length;

        for(let i=0; i< project_attached_images_length; i++) {
            $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/media/' + WPService.project[0].attached_images[i].ID).success(function(res) {
                WPService.project_images[i] = res;

                if(WPService.project_images[i].media_details.width < WPService.project_images[i].media_details.height)
                    WPService.project_images[i].class = 'portrait';
                else
                    WPService.project_images[i].class = 'landscape';
```